# Queryset got bigger after exclusion

Tags: django

This is my shell copy

```
 In [18]: Category.objects.all()                                                 
Out[18]: <QuerySet [<Category: cate uno>, <Category: cate dos>, <Category: cate tres>, <Category: cate cuatro>, <Category: cate cinco>, <Category: cate seis>, <Category: cate siete>, <Category: cate ocho>, <Category: cate ocho>, <Category: cate nueve>, <Category: cate diez>]>

In [19]: catesFat = Category.objects.filter(project__isnull = False)            

In [20]: catesFat                                                               
Out[20]: <QuerySet [<Category: cate uno>, <Category: cate tres>, <Category: cate cuatro>, <Category: cate uno>, <Category: cate diez>, <Category: cate seis>, <Category: cate dos>, <Category: cate uno>, <Category: cate seis>, <Category: cate siete>, <Category: cate ocho>, <Category: cate dos>, <Category: cate cinco>]>

In [21]:
```

It seems fine when I use it in template, but why does it show the redundant queries so it got bigger in shell?

Comment: It does not make redundant queries. It uses a JOIN, and thus returns all records in the JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make redundant queries. It uses a JOIN, and thus returns all records in the JOIN. You can only return *distinct* `Category` objects with [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
catesFat = Category.objects.filter(project__isnull=False).distinct()
```